# Remove parent array and object elements from json - Strapi

Tags: arrays, json, object, next.js, strapi

Currently building an API with **Strapi** with the model of a blog post such that each Post has a `Title, Slug, Content, and user Relation`.

What data looks like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Test1",
        "createdAt": "2022-07-24T18:33:34.195Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-07-24T18:33:34.863Z",
        "publishedAt": "2022-07-24T18:33:34.861Z",
        "user": {
          "data": {
            "id": 1,
            "attributes": {
              "username": "xyz",
              "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
              "provider": "local",
              "confirmed": false,
              "blocked": false,
              "createdAt": "2022-07-24T14:28:16.466Z",
              "updatedAt": "2022-07-24T14:29:00.126Z"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

What I want it to look like:

```
{
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Test1",
      "createdAt": "2022-07-24T18:33:34.195Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-07-24T18:33:34.863Z",
      "publishedAt": "2022-07-24T18:33:34.861Z",
      "user": {
         "id": 1,
         "username": "xyz",
         "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
         "provider": "local",
         "confirmed": false,
         "blocked": false,
         "createdAt": "2022-07-24T14:28:16.466Z",
         "updatedAt": "2022-07-24T14:29:00.126Z"
        }
    }
}
```

By default, the data is wrapped in unnecessarily tiresome arrays and objects and any attempt to edit the `scehma.json` causes the API to crash.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this solution :

````
const x = {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Test1",
        "createdAt": "2022-07-24T18:33:34.195Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-07-24T18:33:34.863Z",
        "publishedAt": "2022-07-24T18:33:34.861Z",
        "user": {
          "data": {
            "id": 1,
            "attributes": {
              "username": "xyz",
              "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
              "provider": "local",
              "confirmed": false,
              "blocked": false,
              "createdAt": "2022-07-24T14:28:16.466Z",
              "updatedAt": "2022-07-24T14:29:00.126Z"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
}
const data = x.data[0]
const users = {id: data.attributes.user.data.id , ...data.attributes.user.data.attributes}
const result = {id: data.id , title: data.attributes.title , createdAt: data.attributes.createdAt ,  updatedAt: data.attributes.updatedAt , publishedAt: data.attributes.publishedAt , user: users }
```
````

Answer (score 2):

you can use strapi-plugin-transformer

https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-plugin-transformer

The plugin configuration is stored in a config file located at ./config/plugins.js. If this file doesn't exists, you will need to create it.

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
   // ..
  'transformer': {
     enabled: true,
     config: {
       responseTransforms: {
         removeAttributesKey: true,
         removeDataKey: true,
       },
     }
  }
});
```